# Activation energy of luminescence

Tags: spectroscopy, crystals

Assuming that activation energy is constant for some range of temperature, it can be determined from the slope of the plot:
$$\ln{I}=A-\frac {E_a}{k_bT}$$
where $I$ - intensity , $E_a$ - activation energy, $k_b$ - Boltzmann constant, $T$ - temperature, $A$ - natural logarithm of pre-exponential factor.
From analogy to activation energy in chemical reactions (where it is energy needed to break intramolecular bonds) this energy need to be given for photoluminescence to occur. However, it is clearly not excitation energy.

1. What is the physical meaning of the activation energy in photoluminescence?
2. Why does it depend on temperature and concentration of dopant?

Comment: PLease identify the variables in your equation  **and** provide a reference link.   BTW,  do you mean "**bio**luminescence" as opposed to various fluorescences?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I can't add a reference link, since the question is based on the information I got from my supervisor and I haven't found any helpful papers. I mean photoluminescence, particularly I examined luminescence of europium doped yttrium orthovanadate under laser radiation.

Comment: Well, that sounds more like electron excitation in the atoms, not a molecular process.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The part about molecular bonds was just comparison, to explain what I do not understand in this case. Maybe I could have worded it better.